# How can I determine if the terminal can display colours in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, windows-terminal

In most terminals, I can use ANSI-Colour-Codes in Python. e.g. `print("\033[92mHello World")` would print out `Hello World` in green. However in other terminals this does not work and it prints the `[94mHello World` literally.

How can I determine if the terminal that is used can display colours **within code**. (This is **not** an issue of determining if an individual terminal can display colours. What I want is to differentiate between terminals within code.)

Comment: Check the `COLORTERM` environment variable.

Comment: Before putting all of your code, just try to make it spit out some colors. If it works, then you know now.

Comment: @KlausD. In the Bash I found the `TERM` variable to include information about the colors (`xterm-256color` in my case). However I can't find such an environment variable for windows.

Comment: @RhinoRunner I'd like my script to find out automatically, without asking the user

Comment: What compiler are you/will you be using?

Comment: @RhinoRunner It's a Python3.x script that will be used with different operating systems (*nix and Windows 10). The main problem are the different types of terminals on Windows.

Comment: I think you may want to specifically look up the parameters for the compiler. Other than that I suggest having a bit of code somewhere where you can copy paste and have it print out a list of colors, so you can see what each one looks like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224629/discussion-between-rhinorunner-and-zciurus-alt-del).

Answer (score 0):

I used this code:

```
import crayons

print(crayons.red('red'))
print(crayons.yellow('yellow'))
print(crayons.green('green'))
print(crayons.cyan('cyan'))
print(crayons.blue('blue'))
print(crayons.magenta('magenta'))
print(crayons.white('white'))
print(crayons.black('black'))
```

To get this:
[image: python image]

So now I know what all of the colors look like for my compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my issue is not determining the capability for an individual terminal. I'd like my script to automatically find out wether the terminal it's run in can display colours.

Comment: If you do something like I did in my answer and one or two (or all) of the colors dont't display, then there ya go you know now.

Comment: Again, this is *not* an issue of determining it for an individual terminal. I want to differentiate between different terminal types *within code*